# Multiple fields in form with play application/form-url-encoded body parser

Tags: scala, playframework-2.1

I have a form

```
<form action="/action" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="email[1]" />
  <input type="text" name="email[2]" />
  <input type="text" name="email[3]" />

  <button type="submit">Submit</submit>
</form>
```

And I have playframework controller which expecting post application/form-url-encoded request

```
def save = Action {
  request.body.asFormUrlEncoded.map { form =>
    println( form )
    Ok("Wop wop wop")
  }.getOrElse {
    BadRequest("Bad bad bad")
  }
}
```

With this code is that I am receiving

```
Map(email[1] -> List(test@test.com), email[3] -> List(), email[2] -> List(test@test.com))
```

instead of

```
Map( email -> Map( 1 -> List(test@test.com), 3 -> List(), 2 -> List(test@test.com) )
```

I need to extract those numbers, because they point on some internal ID's in the database.

Question: how do I extract those numbers? The only way I see now Is to do pattern matching on map names. Maybe there are better options available?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think the better solution here is defining form and then bind it from request.
Try something like that:

```
import play.api.mvc.Action
import play.api.data._
import play.api.data.Forms._

val form = Form(
  mapping(
    "email[1]" -> text,
    "email[2]" -> text,
    "email[3]" -> text
  )(_ :: _ :: _ :: Nil) {
    case first :: second :: third :: Nil => Option((first, second, third))
    case _ => None
  }
)

def myAction = Action{
  implicit request =>
    form.bindFromRequest().fold(errors => BadRequest, data => Ok)
}
```

Comment: I can't hard code those fields, they supposed to be dynamic. This form is intended for customer to supply with all possible contact information. "Possible contact information" is coming from another DB table.

Comment: But your answer is actually gave me an idea of what I can try to do :)